# `__new__` and `__init__` on class and object

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, inheritance

In Python 3, when defining a subclass, why do you need to use `cls` as the first argument of `__new__`, but not to use `self` as the first argument of `__init__`?

An example:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MyClass, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs) # with `cls`
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(MyClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) # without `self`
```

When I compared these functions I got more confused:

```
>>> cls = object
>>> self = cls()
>>> cls.__new__ is self.__new__
True
>>> cls.__init__ is self.__init__
False
>>> self.__init__()
>>> cls.__init__()
Traceback (most recent call last): ...
```

So, what are the differences between `__new__` and `__init__` behind these results? Which methods are bound and which are free? Why are you able to call `self.__init__()` but not `cls.__init__()`? Is `cls.__init__` a method defined in `cls` itself or in its metaclass?

Comment: @TheExorcist: Not a duplicate. This question is completely different.

Comment: I also see you are using new and init as same, then how can you see the difference,.Dont use it for initalize rather change the way of initalize.

Comment: Given that this is not a trivial subject, and you've made some effort to play with it and understand what's going on, +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The biggest part of the picture you're probably missing is that `__new__` is a staticmethod, [special-cased](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) to be one even if you don't use the `@staticmethod` decorator.

When calling a method through `super()`, `super()` performs the same kind of argument binding that would be performed normally for that kind of method (using the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors)). For a staticmethod like `__new__`, that means no arguments are automatically bound, so `cls` has to be passed explicitly. For an instance method like `__init__`, that means `self` is bound automatically, which is why you don't have to pass `self` to `super().__init__`.

Comment: I was wondering why `__new__` is made a static but not a class method, while you still have to pass a class argument.

Comment: @Cyker: With a staticmethod, you can do stuff like `object.__new__(Whatever)`. It'd be a lot more awkward to replicate that functionality with a classmethod.

Comment: But why `object.__new__(Whatever)` while you can `Whatever.__new__()`?

Comment: @Cyker: Because you want to use `object`'s `__new__` method instead of `Whatever`'s.

Comment: Then why don't you want to use `object`'s `__init__` method instead of `Whatever`'s?

Comment: @Cyker: `object.__new__(Whatever)` doesn't call any `__init__` method at all. If you want to call `object.__init__`, you can call it manually on the resulting object, but `object.__init__` doesn't perform any initialization. In any case, the usual reason to call a superclass `__new__` manually outside of a subclass `__new__` is because the subclass `__new__` would refuse to create the object.

Answer (score 1):

`cls` stands for class itself, while `self` stands for object itself. These are just conventions.
The `__new__` method is called **before** the object is created, in fact, `__new__`should create the object and return it. Therefore, it needs a **class** to create object. After that, the `__init__` is called to **initialize** the object, so it needs the object as the first argument.

For example:

```
class MyClass:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # cls == MyClass
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        # cls here is because __new__ is staticmethods so you have to pass the cls explicitly

        # You can't use cls() here because it will call this methods again and again
        # causing recusion error

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Here self is the instance(or object) of MyClass
        # So you can initialize it by self.xxx
        self.xxx = 'xxx'
```

`__new__` is static method, so the class and instance share the same `__new__` method. `__init__` is the method of instance. If you want to call it via class, you need to pass the instance as the first argument explicitly.

```
cls.__init__(self)
```

Anything in Python is object, including the class itself. So for class, it has its own `__new__` and `__init__` which are used by `metaclass` to **create** class and **initialize** class.
These are meta programming of Python, I suggest to read the ninth chapter of Python Cookbook.

Answer (score 1):

The main purpose of [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) is to allocate a new instance of the class, while [`__init__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__)'s job is to set up an existing instance.

According to the docs:

> `__new__()` is a static method (special-cased so you need not declare it as such)

`__init__` on the other hand, is a proper instance method. It can be called multiple times on the same instance, by the way.

That should be enough to explain your terminal session:

```
>>> cls = object
>>> self = cls()
```

You just called `object.__call__`, which essentially does

```
self = cls.__new__()
if isinstance(self, cls):
    cls.__init__(self)
return self
```

Notice that the return value of `__new__` is not required to be an instance of the class it belongs to, but `__init__` is called only if it is. In your case, it is.

```
>>> cls.__new__ is self.__new__
True
```

`__new__` is a static method, so attempting to bind it to the instance does nothing: it stays a class method. This is the same reason that you have to pass `cls` explicitly when calling `super().__new__`: it's the same free function, unbound to either class or instance.

```
 >>> cls.__init__ is self.__init__
 False
```

Not only are these not the same thing, but their types are different. `cls.__init__` is a regular function. `self.__init__` is a bound method which lacks the first parameter of `cls.__init__`.

```
>>> self.__init__()
```

This has already been called, but for `object`, it's a no-op you can call as many times as you like. Notice that the first parameter is not being passed in, being as it is a bound method.

```
>>> cls.__init__()
```

This is calling the raw `__init__` function, which requires that the `self` parameter be passed in. Since you don't do that, it raises. Try this instead:

```
>>> cls.__init__(self)
```

Comment: If `self.__init__()` invokes `__init__` method defined in `type(self)`, why wouldn't `cls.__init__()` invoke `__init__` method defined in `type(cls)`? Isn't a class object also an object?

Comment: @Cyker. Interesting point. Because a method is a non-data descriptor, so any attribute on the instance with the same name will override it. If you do `self.__init__ = some_other_function`, you will see that the other function gets called when you do `self.__init__`. If you hadn't defined `__init__` in the class, it *would* use the one in the metaclass. It's interesting to note that you can't override dunder methods like that on the instance level because dunder methods are always called as `type(self).__dunder__(self, ...)` when used as operators.

Comment: I think if I don't define `__init__` in the class, it would use the one in its superclass. Only if the superclass doesn't have this method it would use the one from its metaclass. But `object.__init__` always exists so the one in its metaclass won't be used.

Comment: @Cyker correct. Object does not have a superclass, which simplifies that case though.